# Передача параметров в build при сохранении в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть 2 модели:

```
class Arendakvartir < ActiveRecord::Base


 has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
 validates_associated :attachments

end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :arendakvartir

  has_attached_file :image,
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
                    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename",
                    styles: { thumb: 'x100', croppable: '600x600>', big: '1000x1000>' }

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"], :message => "Разрешены изображение формата: jpg, png, gif"
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true, :message => "Извини друг без картинок нынче никак"
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 8.megabytes, :message => "Какое то фото явно больше 8 МБ."

end
```

В контроллере вот такая запись:

```
  def new
    @arenda = Arendakvartir.new()
    15.times { @arenda.attachments.build() }
  end


  def create
    @arenda = Arendakvartir.new(arenda_params)

    if @arenda.save()
      @arenda.attachments.create
      respond_to do |format|
          flash[:positive] = "Объект сохранен успешно"
          format.html { redirect_to new_arendakvartir_path }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
          flash[:negative] =  "Объект не был сохранен успешно"
          format.html { redirect_to :back  }
     end
   end
end
```

Это порождает 15 строк добавить файл во вьюхе. Вот код вьюхи:

```
 <%= t.fields_for :attachments do |ph| %>

      <%= ph.file_field :image %>

  <% end%>
```

Вопрос, как бы мне одной строкой через multiple (множественный выбор в форме) выбирать много файлов и при этом сохранять их как сейчас одной строкой @arenda.save()

Comment: Ну, ответ он не принял, помогло ему или нет, мы не знаем. А куда передавать параметры, в том же самом ответе написано, списочком.

Comment: На данный момент вопрос является дубликатом, а то и комментарием к вопросу по ссылке.

Comment: Помогло. Это я же задавал проблема с регистрацией была, открыл запрос со свободной регистрацией.

Comment: Тогда изложите условия эксперимента и чего пытаетесь добиться :)

Comment: У меня есть 2 модели class Arendakvartir < ActiveRecord::Base


 has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
 validates_associated :attachments

end

Comment: Не-не, в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, точно не так.

Поле выбора файлов с `multiple` будет в параметрах выглядеть, как массив файлов.

А то, что у вас, это наборы параметров для `Attachment`, и чтобы оно добавляло произвольное число фотографий, потребуется добавление/удаление форм через JS.

Вариантов у вас два.

---

#### Откажитесь от `Attachment`

Paperclip умеет работать с полями, в которых лежит несколько файлов сразу, при одном условии: соответствующее поле в модели (к которой крепятся фотографии) должно быть массивом. В этом случае никакие nested attributes не будут нужны, да и отдельная модель тоже.

Это хорошая идея, если ваша БД поддерживает массивы, а никакой дополнительной информации к фото прикреплять не планируется.

---

#### ...или приведите параметры в порядок.

Банально во входном фильтре для параметров (где strong parameters) преобразуйте обычный массив файлов в массив наборов параметров для `Attachment`:

```
….map! { |f| { image: f } }
```

При этом форму всё равно придётся изменить, чтобы в ней было поле множественного выбора файлов. Названием у этого поля будет `attachments_attributes`, и обычно оно пишется в `fields_for`, чтобы можно было заполнить несколько таких форм и получить массив моделей. Но поле выбора файлов уже пришлёт массив, и при наличии такого преобразования `fields_for` не нужен.

Есть маленький минус, больше эстетический: выдавать данные из API в таком же формате будет не очень удобно: придётся преобразовывать обратно. Хотя в вашем случае это вряд ли существенно.

Comment: Друг, спасибо! Мне бы просто сначала научиться, а там API  не API если руки уметь будут - перепишем. Буду тебя доставать и дальше!